# Rails : Trouble installing attachement_fu on Heroku

Tags: heroku, ruby-on-rails-plugins, attachment-fu

I'm trying to deploy an app on heroku. 
My trouble is to install hattachement_fu plugin.

I ran the following command to install it directly on the server.

```
heroku plugins:install http://github.com/technoweenie/attachment_fuand"
```

and I get the following message :

```
Unable to load plugin: some_plugin: uninitialized constant ActiveRecord 
Already up-to-date. 
attachment_fu installed
```

So seams that the plugin is installed but something get wrong above ... 
But in my logs I continue to get :

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `has_attachment' for #<Class:0x2b3fed47a830>):
```

Like if the plugin was not there.

Any idea about what's going on ?

Comment: So bad... I found the mistake. I'm not a good git user and I miss adding /vendor file. I deleted the folder and reinstall the plugin then push on heroku and everything is fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's not how plugins work. The command you used is for installing plugins to the heroku command line tool.

If you want to install a Rails plugin, go to your project folder and `script/plugin install foo` (or however your version of rails installs plugins), commit it, then push to heroku.

Comment: I've already installed it ... but I continue to get this error message : NoMethodError (undefined method `has_attachment' for #<Class:0x2b3fed47a830>):

Comment: It's what I did firt.. but seeing the has_attachement not recognized, I supposed heroku needed something else. 
I tried also to uninstall plugin with heroku command line, to test, then to reinstall it but it doesn't works with any solutions. When the app run localy on my laptop everything works, but on Heroku the plugin is not detected... crap
Something really strange, heroku continue to raise this error too :
Unable to load plugin: some_plugin: uninitialized constant ActiveRecord
I also tried to add some require "attachement_fu" in my model, but it's not recognized localy, either on heroku.